emacs fzf.el package gives error: 127 when I execute fzf-find-file-in-directory
I have fzf installed, a fuzzy search find utility, and I have the fzf.el emacs package installed so I can use fzf fuzzy search within emacs. I have the fzf executable on my exec-path, so emacs knows where to find it, and I have configuration options set for fzf within emacs init.el like so:
(use-package fzf
    :bind
    ;; Find file with fuzzy match
    ("<f2> f" . fzf-find-file-in-dir)
    ("<f2> g" . fzf-grep-in-dir)
    :config
    (setq fzf/args "-x --color bw --print-query --margin=1,0 --no-hscroll"
          fzf/executable "fzf"
          fzf/git-grep-args "-i --line-number %s"
          ;; command used for `fzf-grep-*` functions
          ;; example usage for ripgrep:
          ;; fzf/grep-command "rg --no-heading -nH"
          fzf/grep-command "grep -nrH"
          ;; If nil, the fzf buffer will appear at the top of the window
          fzf/position-bottom t
          fzf/window-height 25))

When I execute M-x fzf-find-file-in-directory, I immediately get:
FZF error: 127
And then fzf simply quits. No window, no search results, nothing.
But the thing is, this error only happens in Linux. This exact same configuration works for me on macOS where I also have fzf installed and have the fzf.el package installed for emacs there.
I have no idea what this is or what error:127 means. I have no idea how to even begin to make changes to fix it.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/79243078/1030675

Did you try running fzfwith the specified args from the command line?

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Please don't post the same question to StackOverflow and Emacs StackExchange. Choose one to keep and delete the other. Thx.

Yes I tried running fzf with the specified args from the command line and it works fine. But let's start with what is FZF error: 127?

The message FZF error: 127 is generated by the line 498 in file fzf.el and is
the result of a killed fzf process with other error than successfull 0. This mean there is
something wrong with your command or installation. Check the buffer *Messages* to
see if there are some notes there; you may also enable the debugger and post
the messages, if any.

127 is the code returned by the shell when the command is not found/not in path; so check your Emacs exec-path with C-h v exec-pathand modify it.
